# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel hasMany Relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am pretty new to `laravel` and i am learning about relationships in `eloquent`. I have 3 models

```
Report
ReportModule
ReportSubModule
```

Relationships are such

```
SubModule hasMany Module
Report hasMany ReportModule
Report hasMany ReportSubModule
```

When i try to get the `ReportSubModule` from `Report` object in my view i have no error but when i try to get the `ReportModule` from `Report` object in my view i get error `Trying to get property of non-object`. If i print the `ReportModule` object i see `json` and i think i am getting the object but unable to get it's property

Here is my code

Report (Model)
namespace App;

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Report extends Model
{
    public function report_module(){
        //module_id is column in reports table that corresponds to 
        //id column in report_modules table
        return $this->belongsTo(ReportModule::class,'module_id');
    }


    public function sub_module(){
        //sub_module_id is column in reports table that corresponds to 
        //id column in report_modules table
        return $this->belongsTo(ReportSubModule::class,'sub_module_id');
    }


}
```

ReportModule (Model)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ReportModule extends Model
{
    public function subModules(){
        return $this->hasMany(ReportSubModule::class);
    }

    public function reports(){
        return $this->hasMany(Report::class);
    }
}
```

ReportSubModule (Model)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ReportSubModule extends Model
{
    public function module(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ReportModule::class);
    }
    public function reports(){
        return $this->hasMany(Report::class);
    }
}
```

view

```
<a href="{{route('reports.edit',$report->id)}}"><h4> {{$report ->report_name}} </h4></a>
            <small>{{ $report->sub_module->sub_module_name }} </small><br/><br/>
            <?php
                $m = $report->report_module;
                <!-- i get error on below line -->
                 echo $m->module_name;
            ?>
```

What am i doing wrong here.I should be able to get the `ReportModule` object property just like `ReportSubModule` but i'm not.Please guide me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I assume you have the relationship like this - 

Report id(primary key) -> ReportModule report_id(foreign key)
ReportModule id(primary key) -> ReportSubModule report_module_id(foreign key)

You will have the relation ship in each Model like below -

1) Report Model - 
public function reportModule(){
 return $this->hasMany(ReportModule::class,'report_id'); //you can use has one as well if required
}

2) Report Model - 
//relationship with report table
public function module(){
 return $this->belongsTo(Report::class,'report_id');
}

//relationship with report sub module
public function reportSubModule(){
 return $this->hasMany(ReportSubModule::class,'report_module_id); // you can use has one if required
}
```

and so you can create the relationships..

hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your DB table to have valid value against PK and FK in all relevant tables. For some reason, there may be 0 id is being saved in ID field.